# JSR 2.0 annotations are not inherited by implementation

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, cxf

I'm trying to generate a rest-api using cxf and I have run into trouble, it seems like the PATH-annotation is not inherited correctly or something, If create a method that does not need @Path it works, but when I use Path I have to annotate the implementating method aswell

I have the following Api for use with cxf

```
@Path("/web")
public interface WebApi
{
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}/")
  String getStuff(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

with the following implementation

```
public class WebApiServer implements WebApi
{
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
  @GET
  //@Path("/{id}/") //if I uncomment this line, it works
  public String getStuff(@PathParam("id") String id)
  {
    logger.info("get called with args {}", id);
    return "asdf";
  }
}
```

I'm using CXF version 3.0.1 and javax.ws.rs-api version 3.0.1

my web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>com.richo.merlin.web.api.WebApiServer</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.address</param-name>
            <param-value>/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have also put the entirety of my code here: https://github.com/RichoDemus/stackoverflow-cxf-troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your contract as is, but:

- Move the class level annotations to the concrete implementaions of your `WebApi` interface.
- Remove all method level annotations from the concrete implementation class, **that is redundant**.

After why would you have an interface and many implementations if those can only registered to the */web* URI, and why would you redeclare the annotations if those are already declared in your interface.

If you want to go with other annotations, you would need to overload you methods declared in the interface level because overriding won't do it:

```java
public interface WebApi
{
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}/")
  String getStuff(@PathParam("id") String id);
}


@Path("/web")
public class WebApiServer implements WebApi
{
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  public String getStuff(String id)
  {
    logger.info("get called with args {}", id);
    return "asdf";
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that if I don't put the annotations on the implementing methods, it doesn't work. I know that they should be redundant but they are needed for some reason

Comment: I have a project with you service layer implemented runnig perfectly at local. What version of *CXF* are you using?

Comment: Checkout this project https://github.com/tmarwen/stackoverflow-showcase/tree/master/cxf-rest

Comment: tmarwen, your example works.. not I have to figure out what differs Thanks, I'll post here as soon as I figure it out or need more help

Comment: Here's my code: https://github.com/RichoDemus/stackoverflow-cxf-troubleshoot

I can't find the difference, I've tried using both jetty and tomcat, I've tried changing the cxf version, I've tried changing to java 7, I've tried moving the Api into the same project as the implementation... I must be missing something obvious :/

Comment: I cloned your project, changed the tomcat connector path (just permission issue on my side) and I got it running. I removed all the method and parameter level annotations and it also worked like a charm.

Comment: OMG, finally, it worked when I also removed the parameter level annotation, I was so focused on the method level annotations that I didn't consider that one!
Thank you so much mate, you really did more than I expected, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Inherited type class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), You can't inherit annotations to implementing classes:

> Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

A possible solution is to define an `abstract class WebApiImpl implements WebApi` and inherit from it.